# Recursive Statement, loops through nested objects / Arrays - But How does it know to do that? (JS Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**Question**

We are trying to loop through a series of children and print their names to the console. But if those children have children then we need to print them too.

I have a solution here:

```js
function printChildrenRecursive(t){
  if(t.children.length === 0){
    return
   }
   t.choldren.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child.name)
    printChildrenRecusive(child)
    })
    }
    
 const tree = {
  name: 'John',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Zoe',
        children: [
          {name: 'Kyle, children: []},
          {name: 'Sophia, children: []}
          ]
         }
        }
```

I also struggle to understand how the break out function actually knows that it is done with all of the children.

**Your oversimplified simplified explanation of how this operates would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several typos in your code. I corrected them, and I embedded your code in an HTML file, please see below, which works for me.

Here's the HTML page with your code (corrected typos):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>

    function printChildrenRecursive(t) {
        if (t.children.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        t.children.forEach(child => {
            console.log(child.name)
            printChildrenRecursive(child)
        })
    }

    const tree = {
        name: 'John',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jim',
                children: []
            },
            {
                name: 'Zoe',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Kyle', children: []}, {name: 'Sophia', children: []}
                ]
            }]
    }

    printChildrenRecursive(tree);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the console output:

```
Jim
Zoe
Kyle
Sophia
```

You also asked for an explanation:

- There's a function `printChildrenRecursive(t)` defined which takes an argument `t`. `t` may be any object (this is JavaScript), but the code will assume that `t` has certain properties like `t.children`.

  - The code itself checks if `t`'s property `children` has a property `length` with value zero. If so, the function will terminate.
  - Otherwise, for each of `t`'s children, a new function is executed:
  - print the child's name
  - execute the function `printChildrenRecursive`, and assign the current `child` to argument `t`.
- There's a constant defined called `tree` which is an object containing key-value pairs, e.g. the key `name` is mapped to the value `'John'`, and there's a key `children` mapped to an array which contains more objects.
- The line `printChildrenRecursive(tree)` initiates the execution of function `printChildrenRecursive(t)` and assigns `tree` as the argument `t`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry, appreciated, that was a typing error as I had to write this out manually. (I took it from a video)

Comment: But still can't get my head around it, typo aside

Comment: I modified the answer, correcting more typos, and after creating a working HTML page.

Comment: It makes sense, the only bit that I struggle with is how does the function know to look into the nested objects children as well as the original children. Many thanks

Comment: This is done in the call of 
`t.children.forEach(child => {
            console.log(child.name)
            printChildrenRecursive(child)
        })
`
It iterates of all children, and assigns the current child to `child`. This is used inside the inner function `{ ... }`. Now, in that inner function, the current `child`'s name is printed using console. The next line calls the main function `printChildrenRecursive`, but this time the current child is taken as argument (instead of the `tree` object). This way, the function calls itself for each of its children.

Comment: that helped so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's common that you will have to traverse your nested data for more than just printing names to the console. For that reason, it's useful to separate traversal and the computational effect -

```js
const tree =
  {name:'John',children:[{name:'Jim',children:[]},{name:'Zoe',children:[{name: 'Kyle',children:[]},{name:'Sophia',children:[]}]}]}
  
const traverse = function* (node = {})
{ yield node
  if (node.children)
    for (const c of node.children)
      yield* traverse(c)
}

for (const node of traverse(tree)) // <-- traverse returns iterable
  console.log(node.name) // <-- console.log not part of traverse
  
// John
// Jim
// Zoe
// Kyle
// Sophia
```

We can re-use `traverse` for any kind of computation. For example, below we capitalise names that are longer than 3 characters -

```js
const tree =
  {name:'John',children:[{name:'Jim',children:[]},{name:'Zoe',children:[{name: 'Kyle',children:[]},{name:'Sophia',children:[]}]}]}
  
const traverse = function* (node = {})
{ yield node
  if (node.children)
    for (const c of node.children)
      yield* traverse(c)
}

for (const node of traverse(tree))
  if (node.name.length > 3)
    console.log(node.name.toUpperCase())

// JOHN
// KYLE
// SOPHIA
```

Or we could gather up all of the names in a sorted array -

```js
const tree =
  {name:'John',children:[{name:'Jim',children:[]},{name:'Zoe',children:[{name: 'Kyle',children:[]},{name:'Sophia',children:[]}]}]}
  
const traverse = function* (node = {})
{ yield node
  if (node.children)
    for (const c of node.children)
      yield* traverse(c)
}

const allNames =
  Array.from(traverse(tree), node => node.name).sort()

console.log(allNames)
// [ 'Jim', 'John', 'Kyle', 'Sophia', 'Zoe' ]
```

Comment: What does the asterisk do after the key word: function?

Comment: Andrew, that is a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Answer (score 0):

```
function printChildrenRecursive(object) {
  if (object.children.length > 0) {
   object.children.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(`${object.name}: ${child.name}`);
    printChildrenRecursive(child);
   });
  }
}

const object = {
  name: 'John',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      children: []
    },
    {
      name: 'Zoe',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Kyle',
          children: []
        },
        {
          name: 'Sophia',
          children: []
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

printChildrenRecursive(object);
```